# Why does Json.NET require me to use [DataContract] and [DataMember]?

Tags: .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have hundreds of existing POCOs that I'm currently using with Entity Framework.  A new requirement is that I need to be able to serialize these objects and cache them in Redis. I decided to serialize to JSON using Json.NET but it won't serialize all of my objects.  See the example below.

```
public class Envelope<T>
{
    public string Metadata{ get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass {
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public void Serialize()
{
    Envelope<List<MyClass>> envelope = new Envelope<List<MyClass>>();
    envelope.Metadata = "Some Metadata";
    envelope.Value.Add(new MyClass { MyProperty = "Some Property Data" });
    string json = JsonConvert.Serialize(envelope);
}
```

When this data structure is serialized, everything looks good except `MyClass.MyProperty` is ignored.  The `List<MyClass>` becomes a JSON array with 1 element but that element has no properties.  If I add `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` to `MyClass`, then they are serialized correctly.  I shouldn't have to do this, right?  I didn't have to put those attributes on the `Envelope<T>` class.  I'd rather not have to go through my hundred of POCOs and add these attributes.

Comment: I think there's something else going on in your code that your example above isn't capturing. The code above runs fine in [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dvlMsQ) and produces an output that does include `MyProperty`.

Comment: Which version of JSON.NET are you using?

Comment: Json.Net does not require the use of `[DataContract]` or `[DataMember]`.  In your code, is `MyProperty` public?  If not, that would explain why it is ignored.

Comment: If, in your real code, `MyClass` inherits from a base class with `[DataContract]` applied, then `MyProperty` will not be serialized by Json.NET unless marked with `[DataMember]`.  For a similar problem see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29200648) and [this closed Json.NET issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/603)

Comment: @dbc I think that is my problem.  Some of my POCOs share a base class which has [DataContract].

Comment: Then possibly check out [Configure JSON.NET to ignore DataContract/DataMember attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11055225/3744182).  You may need to manually configure the resolver to  ignore unwanted base class properties though.