# Returning List of List as JSON is returning list values null

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to return list of list as json from my controller,

my controller code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetPpi()
{
    var customer = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>().CurrentCustomer;
    var psg = _xDetailService.GetXDetailbyCustomerId(customer.Id);

    var model2 = new List<List<XDetail>>();

    foreach (var pr in psg)
    {               
        var plan = _xDetailService.GetXDetailbyId(pr.Id);
        var model = new List<XDetail>();
        foreach (var x in plan)
        {
            model.Add(new XDetail
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                XNo = x.XNo,
                XName = x.XName,
                XSurname = x.XSurname
            });
        }
        model2.Add(model);
   }

   return Json(model2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and my ajax call:

```
function GetPlans() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "/XDetail/GetPpi",
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',

    });
}
```

XDetail:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Nop.Core.Domain.UnExpected
{
    public partial class XDetail: BaseEntity
    {
        public int? XNo { get; set; }

        public string XName { get; set; }

        public string XSurname { get; set; }

        public double? XDec { get; set; }

        public int? XMaster_Id { get; set; }

        public virtual XMaster XMaster { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I put a break point at return model2 contains all the values I needed in List of List. But if I continue they return as null.

I am missing something but couldn't find what...

and also using AspNet Mvc 5

Comment: Share your `Json` method?

Comment: Edited the question for your comments

Comment: What is `BaseEntity`?  If it is marked with `[DataContract]` then you will need to annotate your derived class with data contract attributes also.  That's because  AspNet Mvc 5 uses Json.NET for serialization, and Json.NET requires this as explained in [caliburn.micro serialization issue when implementing PropertyChangedBase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29203876/3744182).  Alternatively make `XDetail` be a simple DTO with no parent type.

Comment: @dbc it is just public abstract partial class, not marked with [DataContract].

Comment: Actually It was working fine, just I didn't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$.ajax(..)` call does not provide any success callback function
You can do it like that:

```
function GetPlans() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "/XDetail/GetPpi",
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
           // use result data
        }

    });
}
```

or with promise approach:

```
function GetPlans() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "/XDetail/GetPpi",
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data){
        // use result data
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but my code was already working fine. I just didn't see it. I will accept the answer anyway since it is my fault not to see it :) Ty.