# ASP.NET Core 2.0 WebAPI serialize complex type

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

A ASP.NETCore 2.0 WebAPI Controller has a method:

```
     [HttpGet]
     public IEnumerable<SourceStat> Get()
     {
            return SourceStats.ToList();
     }
     [DataContract]
     public partial class SourceStat: PropertyChangedBase
     {
            [DataMember]
            public long SourceStatId { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public int SourceId { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public InformationUnitType InformationUnitType { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public byte SucceedPercentage { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public DateTime Date { get; set; }

            public Source Source { get; set; }
        }
```

If I don't mark `SourceStat` with `[DataContract]/[DataMember]` attributes, client gets an empty array. But I've seen many examples, where `[HttpGet]` methods return complex objects without such attributes. Why `[DataContract]/[DataMember]` required in my case? What is default serializer used in ASP.NET Core 2.0? Is there a way to mark properties that are not required except marking required ones?

Comment: Possible duplicate?  [caliburn.micro serialization issue when implementing PropertyChangedBase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29200648/3744182).  (You don't show your `PropertyChangedBase` type so I cannot say for sure.)

Comment: @dbc, thanks. I got it, it's because Caliburn's `PropertyChangedBase`. Please reply question 2 and 3.

Comment: By default, you don't need to add the `DataContractAttribute` and `DataMember`. ASP.net core is smart enough to do the mapping automatically to do the mappings for you IF you send a JSON string. Default serializer depends on the request content-type json, xml... You can check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290811/how-to-use-newtonsoft-json-as-default-in-asp-net-core-web-api