# How can I make an attribute non-inherited for a single use?

Tags: c#, attributes, json.net

I know it's possible to [set the inheritance behavior of an attribute you've defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1241121/684776):

```
[AttributeUsage(Inherited = True)]
SomeInheritedAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

But can I alter that behavior for a single use of the attribute? My current use case is the `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` attribute. It's inherited by default, and I'd like to change that for individual uses.

One thought was to define my own attribute inheriting from `JsonObject`:

```
[AttributeUsage(Inherited = False)]
NonInheritedJsonObject : JsonObject
{
}
```

But as Mike pointed out, that class is sealed.

Is there a way to mark an attribute instance (terminology?) as non-inherited?

Comment: You won't be able to inherit from JsonObjectAttribute because it is sealed.

Comment: You can apply `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)]` to the derived type, it will override the `MemberSerialization` for the base type.

Comment: But if you're looking to have different values for `MemberSerialization` for different levels in the inheritance hierarchy, then that is not implemented.  See e.g. [Question about inheritance behavior of DataContract #872](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/872) and [caliburn.micro serialization issue when implementing PropertyChangedBase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29203876/3744182) which indicate that opt-in serialization via `[DataContract]` is inherited throughout the type hierarchy rather than individually controllable on each level in the hierarchy.