# Deserializing object that inherits from ReactiveObject from Json does not work

Tags: c#, json.net, reactiveui

I am trying to deserialize some json into some simple objects that inherit from Reactive UI's ReactiveObject class. For some reason the properties will never get filled there. Using a POCO instead works without any problems.

```
class Program
{
    class Profile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class ReactiveProfile : ReactiveObject
    {
        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _name, value);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var profiles = new List<Profile>()
        {
            new Profile() {Name = "Foo"},
            new Profile() {Name = "Bar"}
        };

        var path = @"C:\temp\profiles.json";

        File.WriteAllText(path,
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(profiles.ToArray(),
                Formatting.Indented,
                new StringEnumConverter()),
            Encoding.UTF8);

        // works
        var pocoProfiles = (Profile[])JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
            File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8),
            typeof(Profile[]));

        // properties not filled
        var reactiveProfiles = (ReactiveProfile[])JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
            File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8),
            typeof(ReactiveProfile[]));

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Delete(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To properly serialize ReactiveObjects you should use the *DataContract* attribute of the System.Runtime.Serialization namespace. Then mark the members you'd like to save with the *DataMember* attribute, and the ones you don't want to save with the *IgnoreDataMember* attribute.

So in your case, something like this:

```
[DataContract]
class ReactiveProfile : ReactiveObject
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    private string _name;

    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _name, value);
    }
}
```

Here's one of Paul's old example usages on Github: [link](https://github.com/paulcbetts/XamarinEvolve2014/blob/46bac6c09f6683cfbefd4a975ff10377d8ad68a7/XamarinEvolve-Core/ViewModels/LoginStartViewModel.cs#L30)

And a documentation link for data persistence: [link](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/data-persistence/)

I ran the code you provided with this change, and it works as expected. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Works perfectly! Can you explain why I have to do this explicitly? Because when I change the Name property on the Poco Profile class to use a backing field it still works there without the attributes.

Comment: @metacircle in short, it's because ReactiveObject has the _DataContract_ attribute. So any property in a derived class not decorated with a _DataMember_ attribute will not be serialized (at least using JSON.net; other serialization libraries may not have this side effect). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29203876/5984310) out for more info. And if you're curious about these attributes, here's a [nice, quick overview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4836803/5984310).