# Unexpected result on serializing an object using Json.NET

Tags: json, inheritance, serialization, json.net, extension-methods

I wrote an extension method to serialize an object to `JSON` using `Json.NET`

```
public static string ToJson(this object value)
{
   if (value == null)
   {
      return string.Empty;
   }
   var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
   {
      ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
   };
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.Indented, settings);
}
```

I have following classes

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class BaseEntity 
{
    [DataMember] 
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class MyEntity: BaseEntity 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

when I run following code

```
var myEntity = new MyEntity{
                  Id = 1,
                  Name = "test"  
                  };
Console.WriteLine(myEntity.ToJson());
```

The output is

> {
>     "Id": 1
>     }

but I expect

> {
>
> "Id": 1
>
> "Name":"test"
>
> }

when I comment `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes the result is as expected, but with these attributes, not, where is the problem?

Comment: @dbc: you are right, my question code run without problem, but I forgot to add some attributes to my code(`[DataContract]`, `[DateMember]`,`[Serialization]`), I updated my question.

Comment: OK then duplicate of [caliburn.micro serialization issue when implementing PropertyChangedBase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29200648): you need to add `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes to the derived class if they're present on the base.

Comment: @dbc: Now my code works like a charm, thank you,